# 6 hours in Melbourne Airport, with bags!

Tags: transit, melbourne

We'll be arriving in Melbourne Airport (Tullamarine) T2 at 06:30 in the morning, but our flight to Hobart (from T1) won't take off until 12:45.
We've been told we'll have to collect our hold luggage, but can't check bags in until 2 hours before the Hobart flight.
I don't know this airport, but some other airports I've been in don't have any seating, shops or restaurants until you get through check-in.
Are we going to be sitting on our luggage in the check-in hall for 4 hours until check-in opens, or are there any areas in Melbourne airport where we could sit in comfort, and even get a drink?

Advice would be appreciated, please, as we'll be arriving from UK via DXB and will have been travelling for almost 22hrs!
Thanks,
Robin.

Comment: According to the airport website https://www.melbourneairport.com.au/Passengers/At-the-airport/Shop-eat there is a reasonable range of facilities for passengers in transit

Comment: @Traveller Are they landside though? He is making an international to domestic connection on separate tickets, so must check in again at Melbourne. I see basically one restaurant landside in T1, and one coffee shop. There's a bit more selection in T2 landside, it seems. I haven't been to Melbourne before either, so I'd want to be a bit more confident if I could.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Melbourne's domestic security did not require me to present a ticket.

Comment: @ceejayoz OK, but do you really think it's a good idea to go through security without checking in and carrying all your hold luggage, considering you would have to come back out and do it again?

Answer (score 6):

There are some shops in the T1 departure area before check-in, but there are even more in the T2 check-in. After arrival at T2, pop upstairs and there will be a reasonable selection of shops and seating. All the terminals are connected, so when your flight check-in opens you can easily walk over to T1. See [Melbourne Airport Maps](https://www.melbourneairport.com.au/Passengers/Passenger-information/Maps) for more detail.

Comment: That's really useful Greg, just what we needed to know. I suppose lugging our cases around won't be too much of an issue on a trolley, and at least we can find somewhere to sit and get drinks/snacks while we wait. Thanks.